# Get the nearest privileges based on the given reputation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a business scenario where I have few edge cases. Let me explain it with the [Stack Overflow Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) data.

Please find the privilege schema creation and sample data: https://rextester.com/KQZS91498

Based on the given reputation input, I need to find the nearest privileges. i.e., the nearest privilege which is less than the given reputation and privilege which can be achieved next.

Example: If I provide my reputation as 7276, I need the following privileges as output:

```
Id  Reputation  PrivilegeName
------------------------------------------
22  5000        approve tag wiki edits
23  10000       access to moderator tools
```

I'm using the following query to achieve it.

```
DECLARE @MyReputation AS INT = 7276;

DECLARE @FromId AS INT = 0;
DECLARE @ToId AS INT = 0;

SELECT @FromId = MAX(Id) FROM @Privilege
WHERE Reputation > 0 AND Reputation <= @MyReputation;

SELECT @ToId = MIN(Id) FROM @Privilege
WHERE @MyReputation > 0 AND @MyReputation < Reputation;

SELECT Id, Reputation, PrivilegeName
FROM @Privilege
WHERE Id IN (@FromId, @ToId)
ORDER BY Id;
```

It gave me the expected result.

Please find the executable query for the same: https://rextester.com/PDEXOM92503.

---

Since I'm using aggregate function to get the Ids, it is not working if a reputation has more than one privilege.

Here reputation **10** contains two privileges. And it is possible in future, it may have three or more privileges.

So the expectation is, if I provide my reputation input as **10** or **13**, I need the output as:

```
Id  Reputation  PrivilegeName
----------------------------------------------
3   10          remove new user restrictions
4   10          create wiki posts
5   15          flag posts
6   15          vote up
```

And for the reputation input of **945**:

```
Id  Reputation  PrivilegeName
------------------------------------------
15  500         access review queues
16  1000        established user
17  1000        create gallery chat rooms
```

ie., the nearest possible privileges based on the given reputation input.

The case is applicable for the reputation like **100**, **1000** which has more than one privilege for the same reputation.

What will be the best way to achieve my expectation which is mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it like following using `UNION ALL`.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                reputation - @MyReputation DIFF 
         FROM   @Privilege) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  diff = (SELECT Max(diff) 
               FROM   cte 
               WHERE  diff <= 0) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  diff = (SELECT Min(diff) 
               FROM   cte 
               WHERE  diff > 0)
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/GABF93013)

Above query can also be written using `CASE WHEN` like following

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                reputation - @MyReputation diff, 
                Max(CASE 
                      WHEN reputation - @MyReputation <= 0 THEN 
                      reputation - @MyReputation 
                    END) 
                  OVER()                   mind, 
                Min(CASE 
                      WHEN reputation - @MyReputation > 0 THEN 
                      reputation - @MyReputation 
                    END) 
                  OVER()                   maxd 
         FROM   @Privilege) 

SELECT Id,Reputation,PrivilegeName,DetailedDescription 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  diff in (mind,maxd)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use two ORed NOT EXISTS conditions two filter the relevant records:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Privilege t
WHERE 
    (t.reputation > @MyReputation AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM @Privilege t1 
        WHERE t1.reputation > @MyReputation AND t1.reputation < t.reputation
    ))
    OR (t.reputation <= @MyReputation AND  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM @Privilege t2
        WHERE t2.reputation <= @MyReputation AND t2.reputation > t.reputation
    ));
```

Comment: It returns all the entries from the table.

Comment: @Arulkumar: I just updated the query, it seems to work fine in the rextester now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `TOP(1) WITH TIES` here. There is no need for subqueries.

You can't put these two queries with `ORDER BY` directly into `UNION ALL`, so I wrapped them in CTEs.

```
WITH
CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
        *
    FROM @Privilege
    WHERE Reputation <= @MyReputation
    ORDER BY Reputation DESC
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
        *
    FROM @Privilege
    WHERE Reputation > @MyReputation
    ORDER BY Reputation ASC
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM CTE2
;
```